# triple boot 2x Windows10 + Linux with EFI - using grub or Windows Bootmanager

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot, grub, bootloader

on my HP notebook I just setup a triple boot system with 2x Windows 10 + Linux Mint partitions (there are reasons why I don't use virtual machines here).

In my BIOS I had to enable UEFI custom boot and point it at EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi (I had run into [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042747/system-bootorder-not-found), found [that solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1103331/1031178)).

Currently the machine boots into a Grub bootloader showing me - among other options - the main Mint entry + an entry for the Windows bootloader. If I select the latter I end up on the Windows bootloader screen (of course) letting me choose between the 2 Windows systems.

Questions:

1. is there a way to by-pass the Windows bootloader but instead configure Grub to directly let me choose between the 2 Windows installations?
2. Or as an alternative: could I by-pass Grub and include Mint into the Windows bootloader? What would I have to do to get rid of Grub and make the Windows B/L the prime one?

If I had the choice I'd prefer option 1

I've seen many descriptions dealing with older Windows versions, or a mix of Windows 10 with one or two older versions. But none seems to explain what I would like to get.
Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile solved it in a different way by just putting the 2 Windows installs onto the internal SSD while installing Linux onto an exernal USB drive. Not quite as fast but much easier to handle

Answer (score 1):

rEFInd

I have a MacBook, with triple efi boot, lnx, win, osx Monterrey and with full disk encryption, possibility to boot boot older bios USB disks also with disk encryption....

Note: turn off all efi secure boot when installing rEFInd and OS....after successful install...then install rEFInd again...then turn on disk encryption and then secure boot.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1128888)

Comment: @gvel50 - thanks for sharing. As I wrote in my own comment I did it differently back then. I still don't like the current solution that much, but well, it works. Once I finde the time though I'll try rEFInd.

Comment: @DarkDiamond - I disagree with your verdict. For me as the one asking gvel50 's post *does* provide an answer